# maven surefire plugin executes excludes also

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, surefire

I have the following configuration for using maven-surefire-plugin to execute my integration tests and unit tests..

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-tests</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*TestCase.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/MySuite.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/BarSuite.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

However, when executing the unit tests it appears to run my individual test classes as well as executing the suite which runs those same classes. How can I configure it to only execute that of which i include? i.e the suite? (MySuite)

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that there appears to be an execution with id `default-test` that occurs even if I don't configure it.

By explicitly configuring an execution with this id, I can control it. In your case telling it to exclude `**` might solve your problem.

Comment: well done !!!
I was unable to setup 2 distinct execustions until I configured one of them with the default-test id

Now it works

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without a build log I can't tell for sure, but from your description here is what I suspect.  The surefire plugin is bound to the lifecycle by default, for jars, wars, ears.  What you have done with your configuration is to add two additional plugin executions, however you did not change the default execution.  You should be able to see this by adding -X to the mvn command and counting the number of surefire plugin executions.

To override the default, change the id of the first execution to "default-test" and see if that does the trick.

[Maven documentation for overriding the default executions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html)